# Make absolute positioned div take up full width of screen

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I have an `absolute` positioned div and I set it to have the full width of the screen with `100vw` but the problem is that it starts where its parent starts and not at the left side of the viewport. How can I get the element to start from left to right?

```css
.main-navigation li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.nav-dropdown {
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    top: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<li id="menu-item-120" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-120">
  <a class="nav-titles" href="http://localhost/wp/checkout/">Clothes</a>
  <div class="nav-dropdown"></div>
</li>
```

E: Added the code. The div that I'm talking about is `.nav-dropdown`.

Comment: `left:0; top:0;`?

Comment: `top:0 left:0 right:0`

Comment: Those do nothing. It just stays at the left side of its parent element, not going to the left of the entire window.

Comment: How is it called from its parent?

Comment: @PaulaLivingstone added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution will be, the element that is set to `position:absolute` will look for the parent with `position:relative`, so if you remove the relative positioning from `li` tag, and move it to the parent `body` tag, it will behave as you wanted! Refer the below snippet.

```css
html, body{
  height:auto;
  margin:0px;
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
}
.main-navigation li {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.nav-dropdown {
    /*display: none;*/
    left: 0;
    top: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    z-index: 2;
    width:100%;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<li id="menu-item-120" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-120">
  <a class="nav-titles" href="http://localhost/wp/checkout/">Clothes</a>
  <div class="nav-dropdown"></div>
</li>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ac aliquet enim. Mauris maximus et dui sit amet fermentum. Aliquam at pharetra enim. Donec porttitor aliquet augue, ac egestas felis. In nec semper purus. Pellentesque sagittis vulputate feugiat. Donec tempor metus a risus interdum, a volutpat purus ultrices. Aenean facilisis diam a nisi dignissim venenatis ac in ipsum. Cras laoreet lacus quis placerat vehicula. Sed finibus justo neque, nec sollicitudin orci rhoncus nec. Etiam at ornare nibh. Proin mollis nisl id odio tempor varius.

Mauris vestibulum tortor et velit lacinia vulputate. Quisque vel tempor augue, at hendrerit tellus. Duis vehicula fringilla nunc, viverra aliquet metus sodales id. Phasellus turpis nisl, pharetra ac libero ac, eleifend interdum sapien. Mauris sit amet fermentum tortor, ut condimentum diam. In tincidunt semper consectetur. Duis id urna blandit, porttitor dolor in, pharetra justo. Proin congue fringilla ante vitae blandit. Mauris vel ultrices elit, ac faucibus nulla. Nam lorem diam, commodo id mauris vel, pellentesque posuere eros. Nullam sit amet metus ut purus condimentum posuere.

Etiam tristique laoreet consectetur. Etiam et orci pellentesque, tristique lacus in, dictum urna. Curabitur venenatis, lacus id vehicula luctus, purus enim aliquam erat, non molestie justo tortor a leo. Sed hendrerit leo vel nisi congue vulputate. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla viverra ultricies accumsan. Mauris auctor massa at leo euismod maximus sed ac turpis. Nam id sapien orci. Quisque eu imperdiet neque. Fusce vel justo orci. Praesent mattis, orci sed imperdiet suscipit, sem sem dictum risus, nec auctor velit turpis at ex. Pellentesque luctus lorem at velit malesuada, id ultricies sem sollicitudin. Donec fermentum egestas nisi, ut blandit leo posuere blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras magna mauris, dignissim sed ligula in, feugiat feugiat lorem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Ut placerat ante arcu, nec lobortis mauris posuere tincidunt. Suspendisse facilisis quis metus id imperdiet. Etiam tempus congue viverra. Nullam in tincidunt erat. Pellentesque feugiat orci sagittis tristique hendrerit. Cras suscipit volutpat imperdiet. Sed ac nulla non nisi tristique aliquam. Nam egestas dolor in feugiat vestibulum. Phasellus in vestibulum diam. Mauris sit amet bibendum ipsum, non faucibus dolor. In suscipit scelerisque lacus non condimentum. Nulla eu viverra libero. Nam mi enim, vulputate at ornare finibus, vehicula at mi. Nulla finibus vel risus vitae tristique. Duis ut ultricies purus, ornare condimentum tellus.

Aenean congue lacus lectus, ac luctus risus scelerisque vitae. Duis sed tempor felis. Donec fringilla aliquet purus. Sed ultricies mauris eu lectus facilisis sodales. Aliquam imperdiet efficitur lacinia. Aliquam tempor sollicitudin sem vitae blandit. Aenean facilisis efficitur finibus. Aenean scelerisque nisl ac lectus viverra, vel elementum nisl ornare. Nam diam erat, volutpat ac tortor id, viverra suscipit nulla.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ac aliquet enim. Mauris maximus et dui sit amet fermentum. Aliquam at pharetra enim. Donec porttitor aliquet augue, ac egestas felis. In nec semper purus. Pellentesque sagittis vulputate feugiat. Donec tempor metus a risus interdum, a volutpat purus ultrices. Aenean facilisis diam a nisi dignissim venenatis ac in ipsum. Cras laoreet lacus quis placerat vehicula. Sed finibus justo neque, nec sollicitudin orci rhoncus nec. Etiam at ornare nibh. Proin mollis nisl id odio tempor varius.

Mauris vestibulum tortor et velit lacinia vulputate. Quisque vel tempor augue, at hendrerit tellus. Duis vehicula fringilla nunc, viverra aliquet metus sodales id. Phasellus turpis nisl, pharetra ac libero ac, eleifend interdum sapien. Mauris sit amet fermentum tortor, ut condimentum diam. In tincidunt semper consectetur. Duis id urna blandit, porttitor dolor in, pharetra justo. Proin congue fringilla ante vitae blandit. Mauris vel ultrices elit, ac faucibus nulla. Nam lorem diam, commodo id mauris vel, pellentesque posuere eros. Nullam sit amet metus ut purus condimentum posuere.

Etiam tristique laoreet consectetur. Etiam et orci pellentesque, tristique lacus in, dictum urna. Curabitur venenatis, lacus id vehicula luctus, purus enim aliquam erat, non molestie justo tortor a leo. Sed hendrerit leo vel nisi congue vulputate. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla viverra ultricies accumsan. Mauris auctor massa at leo euismod maximus sed ac turpis. Nam id sapien orci. Quisque eu imperdiet neque. Fusce vel justo orci. Praesent mattis, orci sed imperdiet suscipit, sem sem dictum risus, nec auctor velit turpis at ex. Pellentesque luctus lorem at velit malesuada, id ultricies sem sollicitudin. Donec fermentum egestas nisi, ut blandit leo posuere blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras magna mauris, dignissim sed ligula in, feugiat feugiat lorem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Ut placerat ante arcu, nec lobortis mauris posuere tincidunt. Suspendisse facilisis quis metus id imperdiet. Etiam tempus congue viverra. Nullam in tincidunt erat. Pellentesque feugiat orci sagittis tristique hendrerit. Cras suscipit volutpat imperdiet. Sed ac nulla non nisi tristique aliquam. Nam egestas dolor in feugiat vestibulum. Phasellus in vestibulum diam. Mauris sit amet bibendum ipsum, non faucibus dolor. In suscipit scelerisque lacus non condimentum. Nulla eu viverra libero. Nam mi enim, vulputate at ornare finibus, vehicula at mi. Nulla finibus vel risus vitae tristique. Duis ut ultricies purus, ornare condimentum tellus.

Aenean congue lacus lectus, ac luctus risus scelerisque vitae. Duis sed tempor felis. Donec fringilla aliquet purus. Sed ultricies mauris eu lectus facilisis sodales. Aliquam imperdiet efficitur lacinia. Aliquam tempor sollicitudin sem vitae blandit. Aenean facilisis efficitur finibus. Aenean scelerisque nisl ac lectus viverra, vel elementum nisl ornare. Nam diam erat, volutpat ac tortor id, viverra suscipit nulla.
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements with `position: absolute` are always positioned against their closest parent with non-static position. If you want to position against the viewport, use `position: fixed` instead.

Comment: I realize that but I can't use `position: fixed` because I don't want it to stay fixed on scroll. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: an absolutely positioned div will float up to the window, OR the first `position:relative` parent. You might have to look for that. You can also use a negative margin to adjust for the offset.